# pytest fill list in setup and use for test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

First of all: There are probably hundreds of answers to this already and I am sorry for asking it, but I just..do not understand.

I want to use a list in certain test-cases which is parsed from a csv-file.
Since I don't want to parse the list multiple times, I want to do that during the setup process.

The pytest documentation recommends fixtures for that.
I figure I use them like this:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def init_my_list():
    return my_service.read_from_csv('my_file.csv')
```

and then call when necessary:

```
def test_get_info():
    test_date = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=8, day=15, hour=6)
    assert (some, values) == myservice.get_prediction_for_datetime(test_date, init_my_list)
```

This returns

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

because the myservice.function iterates over the given list, but the fixture returns a function instead of a list.
All I want is list which is created at the setup, and then can be used in my test cases. How do I achieve this simple task?

Entire Traceback as requested:

> def get_prediction_for_datetime(dt: datetime, prediction_list: list)
>   -> (int, float):
>       try:
>
> > result = next(x for x in prediction_list if
> >                               dt.hour == x[0].hour and dt.day == x[0].day
> >                               and dt.month == x[0].month and dt.year == x[0].year)
> >     E
> >      TypeError: 'function' object is
> >     not iterable

Comment: Could you give us the whole traceback @InDaPond.

Comment: I updated the question with the traceback

Comment: Thanks, InDaPond!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `init_my_list` into the test:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def init_my_list():
    return [1, 2, 3]

def test_1(init_my_list):
    assert init_my_list == [1, 2, 3]  # will succeed

def test_2():
    assert init_my_list == [1, 2, 3]  # will fail
```

Also, by default each fixture is invoked only once per *function*.  If you want to invoke it a single time per *module* or *session*, you need to pass the appropriate `scope=` argument to `fixture`. [See the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session)